# Maze solving- circular path issue

Tags: algorithm, recursion, maze

By keeping records of "was visited" locations (with respect to the direction of the path's progress), up-comes a problem in a specific area in the maze, where the path being tracked is a circular one.
The algorithm that I am using is a recursive one that finds the ***shortest path*** in a maze. It works fine except areas with a circular path.
An example to explain the problem -please see the attached image.
The Black line is the first path that was visited & the Green line is the second path.
The Yellow color, marks the area in the path that was already recorded as "was visited" by the Black line.
Since this Yellow area was already visited, then actually, the Green line in the Yellow area,can not exist.. thus, the Shortest path in the maze in the example can not be found :-(

Any help will be appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiF6g.jpg)

Comment: Why is that yellow portion the only part recorded?

Comment: You solve this by keeping track of nodes that have been visited, as required by the algorithm and mentioned in the question. So what's the question here?

Comment: By "recursive algorithm", you probably mean a depth-first search.  To find the shortest path you should use a breadth-first search instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you reach an already-visited location, you must test to see if the distance on the path you used to reach it the second (or subsequent) time is shorter than the recorded distance at that location. If it is, you must update its distance and continue.

This works as long as there are no "negative" distances. If there were negative distances you stay in the loop forever getting a smaller and smaller distance each time around!

The [Wikipedia page on the Shortest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) lists several algorithms, their constraints, and complexity. For graphs with cycles but no negative distances, these include the Bellman–Ford algorithm, Dijkstra's algorithm with various data structures.